# I keep getting a weird email address trying to facetime me on my iphone5? is this spam?

Tags: facetime, spam

I've received two calls today, both which I ignored, to facetime with an email address that i don't know.  is this spam or an attempt to hack?  has this ever happened to anyone else?  also, the first call was then followed shortly by another weird email, but this time by text.

Comment: My wife and I had one of these calls each from jsmth2@jane-smith.co
Within 10 minutes of each other we both ignored and blocked the caller, think it's some kind of scam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore it and do not reply. It will stop eventually.

You might want to make your Facetime profile private, and consider changing your password just in case.

You might be targeted by a spammer.

Check you settings in Facetime:

[image]

Comment: No harm, ever, in changing your Apple ID password. I'd do it in this case, or anything doubtful / suspicious - and have.